# Improving the Readability of Pivot Chart in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pivot table that contains [910 rows x 1 columns]. When plotted with pandas plot the readability is not good. Please see the image below. I would like to get it as an Excel pivot chart. I mean If I click on a particular point in the chart it should display all the details[Device_ID, Temp etc].

Please see my data frame(Pivot Table).

```
Frequency                  0.8     1.6
Device_ID Temp  Supply                
FF_2649   -40.0 1.65   -100.72 -101.35
                1.71   -100.61 -101.74
                1.80   -100.74 -101.64
                1.89   -100.63 -101.69
                3.60   -100.60 -101.46
...                        ...     ...
TT_2441    85.0 1.65    -94.99  -94.97
                1.71    -94.85  -95.24
                1.80    -95.02  -94.97
                1.89    -94.69  -96.20
                3.60    -94.90  -94.91
```

Could you please tell me how can Improve the readability?

May I know is there any way to plot this as an excel file.

[image]

Comment: a possible answer is use plotly instead of matplotlib...  that does have the tooltips and interaction.   it would be much simpler to demonstrate if you provide sample data as text

Comment: It is very difficult to paste here .It is not coming as expected. I can email you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- synthesised data against a multi-index to be similar to question
- Using **plotly** as your plotting backend tooltips are then part of the solution
- currently multi-indexes are not supported so I changed to a concatenated index to demonstrate

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list("abcd"), list("efgh"), list("xyz")], names=["cat1","cat2","cat3"]))
df["value"] = np.random.randint(1,200, len(df))

pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
df.reset_index().pipe(lambda d: d.set_index(d.cat1+d.cat2+d.cat3)).loc[:,"value"].plot()
```

[image]

#### using plotly API with multi-index

- need to combine multi-index into **x**
- from your comments I assume there are multiple columns too.  Generate a plotly scatter for each column

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

s = 100000
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"Device_ID":np.random.choice(["FF_2649","FF_2700","FF_2800","TT_2000","TT_2100","TT_2441"], s),
                      "Temp":np.random.randint(-8, 19, s)*5,
                       "Supply":np.random.choice([1.65,1.71,1.80,1.89,3.60], s),
                       "Frequency":np.random.choice([0.8,1.6], s),
                       "NoiseLevel":np.random.uniform(-102,-94, s)
                      })

multi_index = pd.pivot_table(df_new, index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp' ,'Supply'],columns = 'Frequency', values = 'NoiseLevel',)
# given data is randmoly generated, give it some order...
multi_index.loc[:,[0.8,1.6]] = multi_index.assign(p=lambda d: (d[0.8]*2)+(d[1.6]*.5)).sort_values("p").drop(columns="p").values

# pivot gives a column per frequency.  SO question did not indicate this....
# generate a line for each column in pivot table.  concat values of multi-index to make it work with plotly
data = [go.Scatter(x=[" ".join([str(p) for p in x]) for x in multi_index.index], y=multi_index[c], 
                   mode='lines+markers', name=f'Noise Level {c}', marker={"size":10},line={"dash":"dot"})
 for c in multi_index.columns]
layout=go.Layout(title='Noise Level') 
figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout) 
figure
```

[image]

Comment: I will try this and let you know.Thank you for your time.

Comment: I tried with this code" data=[go.Scatter(
x=multi_index.index,
y=multi_index.values,
mode='lines',
name='Noise Level'
)]
layout=go.Layout(title='Noise Level')
figure=go.Figure(data=data,layout=layout)
pyo.plot(figure)"I am getting a straight line.I don't know here to put pivot table column in the code

Comment: I've updated - still need to structure multi-index in way that deals with constraints

Comment: multi_index = pd.pivot_table(df_new, index = ['Device_ID', 'Temp' ,'Supply'],columns = 'Frequency', values = 'NoiseLevel',)---This is my Pivot table,
#This is my code:Dont know where to put "columns = 'Frequency'"
data=[go.Scatter(
x=multi_index.index,
y=multi_index.values,
mode='lines',
name='Noise Level'

)]

Comment: for your next SO question or any additional iteration on this one.  Best to follow SO guidelines and provide a representative dataset for your question.  I still don't know if what I have simulated matches what you are working with

Comment: Sure next time onwards I will follow the guideline.I have added my data frame. Please check it.Thank you for your time.

Comment: ok - I've change code that randomly simulates data that matches your shape.  The plotting technique does not change at all.  Did decide to use space instead of underscore to delimit concat string to represent index value as underscore is included in device id

Comment: You are correct . There are two columns one for Frequency 0.8 and the other for 1.6